# UICollectionView displays empty and doesn't show any cells

Tags: swift

I am just testing the code to see if it can load the collection view. But id doesn't show anything. Please look at the code below and let me know where I am wrong.

```
import UIKit
    

private let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"
class FeedController: UICollectionViewController {

   
    //MARK: - Lifecycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    configureUI()
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }
    
    
    //MARK: - Helpers
    
    func configureUI() {
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
        collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
       
    }
}
//MARK:- UICollectionViewDataSource

extension FeedController {
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }
    
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = .systemRed
        return cell
    }
}

extension FeedController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 200)
    }
}
```

Comment: You must not register a default `UICollectionVievCell`

Comment: That doesn't change anything.

Comment: @vadian is there anything else that I can do to see if it works?

Answer (score 0):

Set a breakpoint somewhere in `viewDidLoad` to test if it even calls any code of this class when running the app.

Normally you get an error when you set the `dataSource` and `delegate` in a `UICollectionViewController`, because these are already set by the controller. Because of this, move the extension lines to the main class and remove the extension.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize `FeedController` using `public init(collectionViewLayout layout: UICollectionViewLayout)` UICollectionViewController initializer, else you have no layout assigned to the UICollectionView.

Wherever you are doing `FeedController()` you should do `FeedController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())` or some custom UICollectionViewLayout.